# Cassandra clustername mismatch

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cluster-computing, cassandra-0.7

I'm trying to add a single node to an already existing cluster called ClusterA.
Prior to bootstrapping this node, it was running a single node cassandra cluster called "Test" with an older version 0.7.4. ClusterA is running 0.7.5 and I've upgraded the node to be added to 0.7.5 as well. I configured the yaml properly, but when I run Cassandra I get spammed with the following:

```
INFO 20:04:24,262 Logging initialized
 INFO 20:04:24,275 Heap size: 5156896768/5156896768
 INFO 20:04:24,276 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 20:04:24,284 Loading settings from file:/usr/local/bin/apache-cassandra-0.7.5/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 20:04:24,380 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 20:04:24,511 Creating new commitlog segment /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1306267464511.log
 INFO 20:04:24,525 Couldn't detect any schema definitions in local storage.
 INFO 20:04:24,525 Found table data in data directories. Consider using JMX to call org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.loadSchemaFromYaml().
 INFO 20:04:24,535 No commitlog files found; skipping replay
 INFO 20:04:24,553 Upgrading to 0.7. Purging hints if there are any. Old hints will be snapshotted.
 INFO 20:04:24,556 Cassandra version: 0.7.5
 INFO 20:04:24,556 Thrift API version: 19.4.0
 INFO 20:04:24,556 Loading persisted ring state
 INFO 20:04:24,558 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 20:04:24,588 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@1048095360(233 bytes, 4 operations)
 INFO 20:04:24,589 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@1048095360(233 bytes, 4 operations)
 INFO 20:04:24,794 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-1-Data.db (341 bytes)
 INFO 20:04:24,822 Joining: getting load information
 INFO 20:04:24,823 Sleeping 90000 ms to wait for load information...
 WARN 20:04:24,885 ClusterName mismatch from /10.44.2.58 Test !=ClusterA
 WARN 20:04:24,886 ClusterName mismatch from /10.44.2.58 Test !=ClusterA
 WARN 20:04:24,886 ClusterName mismatch from /10.44.2.58 Test !=ClusterA
 WARN 20:04:24,886 ClusterName mismatch from /10.44.2.58 Test !=ClusterA
 WARN 20:04:24,887 ClusterName mismatch from /10.44.2.58 Test !=ClusterA
```

This IP does not exist anywhere in the new yaml. It's an old config I tried implementing some time ago, but I'm *not* trying to cluster with this ip at all. 
I tried deleting all the storage, db files, and old configs, but it still detects an old seed IP somehow.

I find it weird that this gets logged when I confirmed that the data directory is empty.

**Found table data in data directories...**

Can anyone tell me how this is still coming up during start up? What do I need to change/remove/delete for this IP to go away?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#clustername_mismatch , which says:

> "To prevent operator errors, Cassandra
>   stores the name of the cluster in its
>   system table. If you need to rename a
>   cluster for some reason, it is safe to
>   remove system/LocationInfo* after
>   forcing a compaction on all
>   ColumnFamilies (with the old cluster
>   name) if you've specified the node's
>   token in the config file, or if you
>   don't care about preserving the node's
>   token (for instance in single node
>   clusters.) "

Comment: yes, i've already nuked out the whole cassandra/data directory. The system directory is complete empty, but the old config/ip still shows up during startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cassandra nodetool to disable gossip to this(unwanted) node.

1. Go to cassandra/bin directory
2. Say "nodetool -h ip_creating_issue disablegossip"

try using other options of the nodetool like "decommission"

disable gossip worked fine for me.