# Error rename cassandra cluster name 1.2.6

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 1.2.6 in cluster with a single node. I am trying to rename the cluster using the instructions in:

[Cassandra clustername mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116852/cassandra-clustername-mismatch)

After doing all the steps indicate I continue with the same error when I start cassandra after change the cassandra.yaml file

Do anyone Know if it is a problem of cassandra 1.2.6?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty the /var/lib/cassandra/data ,/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog ,/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches directory and restart Casandra after changing cluster name . This works very well in version 1.2.4 ,try with your version .

It is recommended to use stable release of in envelopment product, if not done with above  use 1.2.5 or 1.2.4 instead.

Comment: Sorry I was using the version 1.2.4. If I empty /var/lib/cassandra/data I lose all the data no? Can I simply restore the data again copy the content of the folder?

Comment: Its not proper way, may or may not work. before this take back up of your keyspace http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore

Comment: the backup_restore link that you point is useful if you dont delete the system keyspace. But if I delete the data folder as you indicated the system keyspace is lost.

Comment: In order to change keyspace name from default name to your name you have to remove system key space... as far as your keyspace concern go to cli and enter show schema,this will generate keyspace,CF creation code for you and just copy that and after establishing with new cluster name ,this will create your keyspace and than restor data that you backed up

Comment: thanks Hardik. I will try to restore the data as you explain to me.

Comment: By the way you describe works but I have to recreate all the schema (column familys, etc...). In the cassandra FAQ http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#clustername_mismatch they say that it is not needed but I always get the mismatch name when i tried to start cassandra

Comment: yes you are right..I am also working on ring management..get back to you when have proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

Executing the following command using cqlsh worked for me (on Cassandra 1.2.9):

`update system.local set cluster_name='$CLUSTER_NAME' where key='local';`

You'll need to get it working first to access the cluster by setting cluster_name in cassandra.yaml to the old name. Afterwards, you can run a `nodetool flush`, update cassandra.yaml, and restart Cassandra.

Comment: Running cassandra 2.2.1 on Windows, I had to run 'nodetool flush system' in order to get this to work.  Nodetool flush wasn't sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Clear `/var/lib/cassandra/data`, `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`, `/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches` directories and restart Casandra after changing cluster name. This works very well in version 2.0.2

Comment: I have tried all that since last about 1 hours :). No avail. I have also tried cassandra-cli. -- [default@system] set LocationInfo[utf8('L')][utf8('Test Cluster')]=utf8('Single Node Test Cluster');
LocationInfo not found in current keyspace.

Comment: I also tried using cqlsh and select * from local, here is what I get - local |    COMPLETED | Single Node Test Cluster |       3.2.0 | datacenter1