# DATASTAX Cassandra Cluster naming stops windows services in WINDOWS 8

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have downloaded cassandra `datastax-ddc-64bit-3.4.0.msi` and installed it to WINDOWS 8 .I runs ok. But when i edit  `cassandra.yaml`

`cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'`
to

`cluster_name: 'MyCluster1'`

then the services does not start.

I check error log in `C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\logs\datastax_ddc_server-stdout.2016-04-04.log`.

it shows

```
    ERROR 09:08:34 Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name MYCLUSTER
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:915) ~[apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$8.execute(StartupChecks.java:297) ~[apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:106) ~[apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:169) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:680) [apache-cassandra-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
```

what is the problem with my cluster name ??? Am i missing something??? why there are 3 log files in Log directory?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, **the saved cluster name value is not equal to the configured cluster name**. Which means, Once if you start the cassandra for very first time, it will take the cluster name from yaml configuration file and save the cluster name  in the  column family **`local`** which is available in **`system`** keyspace. So if you try to restart it again for second time, it will try to retrieve the cluster name from the saved data (system.local) and compare it with yaml configration. So In your case you have created the cluster in the name of **`Test Cluster`** for the very first time, so the cassandra expects the cluster name as **`Test Cluster`** for every startup process. If you want to change the cluster name then this [link](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205289825-Change-Cluster-Name-) explains the step more clearly. You can retrieve the saved cluster name by the following cql query,

```
select * from system.local;
```

Comment: There is another problem i am facing this is my **Cassandra CQL Shell** not starting ? why ?

Comment: What error you are facing while trying to executing CQL shell?

Comment: By Default, cqlsh will try to connect through 127.0.0.1 but if you start cassandra with private IP as listen_address (In cassandra.yaml) then you need to start cqlsh by, cqlsh <private_address>

Comment: Where to modify **cqlsh** ??

Comment: You dont need to modify just try to start in command prompt as `>cqlsh xxx.xx.20.3` where xxx.xx.20.3 is the IP that you have been configured for `listen_address` in cassandra.yaml

Comment: My listen address is     `listen_address: localhost `  in **cassandra.yaml** and cmd showing `cqsql is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: What exception are you getting? Image that you have uploaded is different from the above comment. The command is `cqlsh` not `cqsql`

Comment: If you configured listen_address as `localhost` then try to start in command prompt as `cqlsh localhost`

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash If this post has answered your initial question, then please mark it as such.  If you have additional question(s), then please ask a new question, but don't carry on an extended discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and found an answer on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162999/error-rename-cassandra-cluster-name-1-2-6)

> Empty the /var/lib/cassandra/data ,/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
>   ,/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches directory and restart Casandra after
>   changing cluster name . This works very well in version 1.2.4 ,try
>   with your version .
>
> It is recommended to use stable release of in envelopment product, if
>   not done with above use 1.2.5 or 1.2.4 instead.